# Installing R in Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.1 (Maipo)

Tags: r, linux, rhel7

I am trying to install R on RHEL 7 but i get the following error.

```
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.2.3-4.el7.x86_64 (epel)
       Requires: blas-devel >= 3.0
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.2.3-4.el7.x86_64 (epel)
       Requires: lapack-devel
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.2.3-4.el7.x86_64 (epel)
       Requires: texinfo-tex
```

I installed epel-release-7-8.noarch. I also tried to group install Development tools as below.

```
yum group install "Development tools"
```

Tried to enable repos

```
yum-config-manager --enable epel
```

I tried several suggestions posted in internet. but nothing seems to work or solve my issue. Can somebody help me install R? It should be a simple three steps process but now it became a nightmare for me to complete it. Please find below system details.

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.1 (Maipo)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should just install couple of dependencies.

```
$ sudo dnf -y install blas-devel lapack-devel texinfo-tex
```

Comment: Hello, I tried it. It gives me message "No package blas-devel available." and same message for rest of the package. Any suggestion? Many thanks.

Comment: I also use help from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708213/install-r-on-redhat-errors-on-dependencies-that-dont-exist) but still I am getting error likes :  Error: Package: blas-devel-3.2.1-4.el6.x86_64 (/blas-devel-3.2.1-4.el6.x86_64)
           Requires: libblas.so.3()(64bit)